# jquery filter as well as returning expression that evaluated to true

Tags: javascript

I'm using a jQuery search method with multiple `||` expressions, any one of which can return `true` in order to display the result. My goal is to retrieve which of the expressions actually evaluated to `true`:

```
return this.itemAry.filter(function(item){
   var that = this;
   return (
     item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.search.toLowerCase())>=0 ||
     item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.search.toLowerCase())>=0
   )
 });
```

So if the `item.name` piece evaluated to `true`, I'd like to not only filter results that return `true`, but to also know that it was `item.name` versus `item.description` that evaluated to `true`.

**Edit with example:**

In my itemAry I can have

```
{item1: {name: "foo", description: "bar"}, item2: {name:"baz", description:"bar"}}
```

So if I search "foo" - I'd like to not only return the item1 object, but to also let me know that it was this expression `item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.search.toLowerCase())>=0` that evaluated to `true`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this: *I'd like to not only **filter results** that return true, but to **also** know that it was [propertyname]* - can you provide a use-case (ie some calling code and how you'd use the result).

Comment: So right now it acts as a basic filter where if any of the expressions evaluate to true, it returns the items in the array that match any of the expressions. I'd like to go one level deeper and show me which specific expression caused the results to evaluate to true, so out of the two options here, I'd like to know which option it was that made it true. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to store the field you found it in:

```
const searchResults = this.contractsAry
    .map(function(item) {
        return ({
            item: item,
            nameMatches: item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0,
            descriptionMatches: item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        })
    }.bind(this))
    .filter(function(item) {
        return item.nameMatches || item.descriptionMatches
    });

searchResults.forEach(function(result) {
    console.log(result.item, result.nameMatches, result.descriptionMatches)
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this one to work and I feel it's on the right path and console.log returns the correct results, but I can't seem to get it to return the correct set of filtered items

Comment: Edit: just got it to work this this: 
    `return searchResults.map(function(result){
            return (result.item)
          });`
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Truthfully, not possible without either changing the object (add a new key to object), or checking again by loop.

Logical operators just don't work that way.

To add a new key just add both to the object, as a simple && won't work(you would actually have use both AND and XOR).